# Invoke SAML IdP from Javascript

Tags: ajax, weblogic-10.x, adfs2.0, saml-2.0

Again I need the wise advise of the Community!!!

I have to integrate several Web Applications in my SSO system. The IdP is Active Directory Federation   Sevices (ADFS2) and the SP's are Weblogic Managed Servers. I am using HTTP-POST binding for the SP-initiated Use Case in the Web SSO profile.

This setup is working and even I have implemented the SLO for WLS, great! but, there is always a but... I have an application that can be accessed for unauthenticated users, **guest users**. When the user is authenticated he/she will see different information.

**What do you think that would be the best approach for implementing this?**

I am trying to perform a JavaScript call to the IdP, through **XMLHttpRequest**, but it is not working as I was expecting... My idea is not to build the SAMLRequest by myself. This is, instead of invoking directly the IdP, I am requesting a secure resource of my app. In this way is Weblogic the one that make the request to the IdP (302 redirect). Basically mi idea is the next:

1. Declare a security-constraint in my web.xml:

   ```
   <security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name>secure</web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>FederatedUsers</role-name>
   </auth-constraint>
   ```
2. Invoke a secure resource (thanks w3schools!):

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "secure/login?action=sample/hello.jsp", false);
   xmlhttp.send();
   xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
   ```
3. The implementation of the secure resource is just a **servlet** that redirects to the original resource:

   ```
       // Get the parameter "action" and redirect 
   resp.sendRedirect(req.getParameter("action"));
   ```

More or less it does the trick, if we take a look at the request flow:

1. http://spHost/sample/helloXmlHttpRequest.jsp
2. http://spHost/sample/secure/login?action=sample/hello.jsp
3. HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily --> https://idpHost/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=...

But at the end I get an **error** in the **xmlhttp.send()**: **Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)**

Also I am trying to do *nasty tricks* like get the content  of an *iframe*, element, or just call the secure resource in a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="secure/login">
```

The problem of this last *"solution"* is that I am not able to get the HTML code.

**Any ideas?** Maybe ADFS2 provides any REST service or something like that...

Thanks in advance,

Luis

Comment: ADFSv2 does not expose any REST endpoints by default.

Comment: Thank you very much Sean! So what would you suggest me? I am thinking in developing a Javascript function that would send a SAMLRequest to the IdP. Depending on the response it would return true or false. But I am wondering if it would not be to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: Hmm. The usual WS-Federation site (site/adfs/ls by default) is really reliant on the passive redirection behavior. Thus it might not behave correctly when done via an asynchronous JS approach... dunno. It's certainly venturing into questionable territory, though not wheel-reinvention. I'm afraid I haven't got any suggestions, though... sorry!

Comment: Not sure if you are still interested in this idea since it was posted 2012 but have you considered the ECP SAML profile? The ECP profile would allow you to depart from the notion of having to use a redirect as a vehicle for SSO authentication.

Comment: Not sure if I am understanding your comment Nick. I do believe that the aim of the ECP (Enhanced Client and Proxy) profile is to support other scenarios. Please take a look at  http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.html#5.2.ECP%20Profile|outline